# I want to pass this query to Eloquent in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make a query with eloquent, I try to get all the users who have one or more ads, taking into account that it is a one to many relationship (users to ads).

This query in general does what I want, but I do not know if it is well done and also how to pass it to Eloquent through the User model.

```
 SELECT users.id, COUNT( anuncio.id ) AS  'total' FROM users 
INNER JOIN anuncio ON users.id = anuncio.usuario_id WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM anuncio WHERE anuncio.usuario_id = users.id) >0 
GROUP BY users.id ORDER BY total DESC
```

I have tried several ways that only return Builder to me.
For example:

```
$listas = new User;
        $listas = $listas->join('anuncio','users.id','=','anuncio.usuario_id');
        $listas = $listas->select(array('users.*', DB::raw('COUNT(anuncio.id) AS total')));
        $listas = $listas->where(function($query) use ($listas){
            $query->select(DB::raw('COUNT(anuncio.usuario_id)'))
                    ->where('anuncio.usuario_id','=','users.id')
                    ->groupBy('anuncio.usuario_id');
        },'>','0');
        $listas = $listas->orderBy('total','DESC')->paginate(48);
```

By any suggestion I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$listas = User::join('anuncio','users.id','=', 'anuncio.usuario_id')
->select('users.id',DB::raw("count(anuncio.id) as total"))
->groupby('users.id')
->having('total', '>', '0')
->orderby('total', 'desc')
->get();
```

Comment: This is the result: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'total>0' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` inner join `anuncio` on `users`.`id` = `anuncio`.`usuario_id` group by `users`.`id` having `total>0` = )...

Don't recognize column total, I tried to change ->having('total','>',0)  but the same error

Comment: replace  `having ('total>0`) with following
`->having('total', '>', '0')`

Comment: In config/database.php change strict  values. Set it to false

Comment: It's works, thank you so much, but now I have problem to use paginate() you know why?

Comment: We can make the code working by changing the alias total to aggregate. But according to standards  i don't know whether that is proper or not.

Comment: `$listas = User::join('anuncio','users.id','=', 'anuncio.usuario_id')
->select('users.id',DB::raw("count(anuncio.id) as aggregate"))
->groupby('users.id')
->having('aggregate', '>', '0')
->orderby('aggregate', 'desc')
->paginate();`

Answer (score 0):

Just use left join for this.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->leftJoin('anuncio', 'users.id', '=', 'anuncio.usuario_id')
            ->get();
```

So `Left Join` will only select those result which has any match in `anuncio` table.